# Is it safe to remove these files with "microsoft" in the name?

Tags: kernel, uninstall, microsoft

I just did:

```
sudo updatedb  
locate * microsoft *
```

and it told me this:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-microsoft.ko
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/microsoft
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1251.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1255.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1256.html
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1250.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1251.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1252.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1253.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1254.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1255.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1256.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1257.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1258.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-win3.1.enc.gz
/usr/share/mime/image/vnd.microsoft.icon.xml
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic/include/config/hid/microsoft.h
```

Is it safe to remove them, or some of them (please specify)?
Because I want the least possible microsoft or windows on my system!

Comment: Why would you remove them? They are not part of Windows, or necessarily from Windows. One is a driver for some Microsoft hardware, and the header file in the kernel source tree. Another is a MIME type definition for the .ico file format. Most are just character encoding definitions. Deleting the files would break packages (and would get replaced by later updates anyway).

Comment: (but, seriously, don't remove the kernel packages from your system.)

Comment: Why are people still arguing and commenting on this? The question was already answered and accepted.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

These files have nothing to do with Windows, and are not from Microsoft. Deleting them will simply break some of the packages you have installed (and any features which rely on those files being there), and those files will simply be replaced when those packages get updated later anyway. There's no point in removing them.

Comment: From my understanding, most of these are character encodings used by Windows to extend ASCII, but nowadays they are used for legacy purposes since Unicode is the norm.

Comment: @qwr Yes, they are definitions for character encodings in X11. What they are however, is immaterial to the question of "is it ok to delete them," which is generally answerable by "no, deleting files manually, which are managed by packages, is not a good idea."

Answer (score 22):

These files fall into four groups:

```
/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-microsoft.ko
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic/include/config/hid/microsoft.h
```

These are drivers and support files for Microsoft-branded input devices (keyboards and mice).  They are vaguely Microsoft-related, but probably contain no Microsoft code.  You can probably remove them safely, though if you've got Microsoft hardware, you might lose things like support for media keys or extra mouse buttons.  I don't think any Microsoft hardware is completely incompatible with the generic USB or PS/2 drivers.

```
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
```

These are part of the Grub bootloader, used to detect if there is a Microsoft operating system present or not on a separate partition/volume.  I'm not familiar enough with the internals of Grub to say if deleting them would be harmless, or if it would break your system entirely.

```
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1251/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1255/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/Compose
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/XI18N_OBJS
/usr/share/X11/locale/microsoft-cp1256/XLC_LOCALE
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/microsoft
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1251.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1255.html
/usr/share/doc/libx11-dev/i18n/compose/microsoft-cp1256.html
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1250.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1251.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1252.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1253.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1254.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1255.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1256.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1257.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1258.enc.gz
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-win3.1.enc.gz
```

These are files describing the Windows cp125* family of [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).  You don't want to remove them: things will break badly if you ever visit a website using one of these encodings (about 5% of the web) or try to open a text document using one of them.  They're Microsoft-related only in the sense that they describe Microsoft practices.

```
/usr/share/mime/image/vnd.microsoft.icon.xml
```

This simply describes the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) for the [Windows Icon file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)).  Removing it means that `.ico` files will be described as "Data file" rather than "Windows Icon", but shouldn't have any other effects.

Comment: Don't remove the "microsoft" files from the kernel source if you want to build the kernel.

Comment: Those particular encoding files probably aren't used for much, incidentally - they're more commonly called e.g. "windows-1252" or just "cp1252" - the *most* important one for that encoding is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1252.so. But removing them is still silly.

Comment: You have misidentified the purpose of at least two of the files. The "os-probes" files are related to the detection of microsoft operating systems when building the grub boot menu.

Comment: @PeterGreen, fixed.

Answer (score 8):

You could find out which package these files are part of, then decide that removing that package is wrong, by:

```
locate *microsoft* | xargs -n 1 dpkg -S
```

Of course, read `man xargs` and `man dpkg`.

Comment: This is actually rather dangerous advice.  If I'm correct about how Ubuntu organizes its packages, only one of the files belongs to a package that's safe to remove, while the majority belong to packages that will break things in new and exciting ways if removed, and one belongs to a package that, if removed, will require re-installing the system to recover.

Comment: @Mark Please explain how it's "dangerous"?

Comment: Because it's not clear to the average user what the purpose of a given package is, or what other files it may include.  I don't have an Ubuntu system to check right now, but on my Gentoo system, `/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/microsoft-cp1250.enc.gz` is from a package with the  innocuous-sounding name of "encodings".  `/lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-microsoft.ko` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic/include/config/hid/microsoft.h` are both from packages with "kernel" in their names, but one is safe to remove and the other will destroy your system.

Comment: @Mark the answer explicitly says, "*then decide that removing that package is wrong*".  That leaves no question whether or not it's safe to remove.

Comment: @Mark This answer says "This is how you determine what a file belongs too"... This is a vital part of knowing if the files can be deleted since, as you say, deleting specific packages will hose your system. He didn't say "Determine the package and uninstall them" - which is what you seem to be railing against. How else would you suggest someone determine where files come from? Does it need multiple warnings since everything has to be covered in bubble wrap these days?

Comment: @WernerCD, the average user doesn't have the knowledge needed to correctly decide "can this package be safely removed?".  What they'll get from this command is a list of names such as `linux-headers`, `xkb-data`, and `xfonts-encodings`, some of which sound safe to remove, and others of which don't.

Comment: @Mark 1) The "Average user" wouldn't use the command line and ask questions here... 2) You don't learn by not doing. And you don't teach by saying "Your too dumb to understand this, so stay away". 3) The ANSWER to this question is "What do those files belong too? These packages... should you delete those packages? research further in other questions". Saying "you can't understand this" is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're running Ubuntu or a derivative thereof, you don't have to worry about "Having Microsoft or Windows" on your computer unless you went out of your way to install WINE. You're free to do whatever harm to yourself or your system you wish.

As with all advice given: User Beware.

Comment: WINE is neither Microsoft nor Windows. It's a re-implementation of the Windows programming interface (API) to allow applications written for Windows to run on a Linux system.

Comment: That is the most accurate way to state things, what I was trying to suggest is that, without WINE for them to sit on/in those sorts of programs aren't doing anything.